# How we work on choosing an ideal covariate in ANCOVA (comparing covariates)

Tags: anova

Does the scaling of the covariate matter when using ANCOVA?

ex:I conduct an experiment between 2 methods A and B, example an elementary instruction and want to find out which method is more effective 
Y=the measure of learning 
X=the measure of intelligence (my covariate)
Now obviously getting a sample of Y alone is easy but how would I choose the measure of computer knowledge? 
group A
a Xa=88  Ya=66, b Xb=98  Yb=85, c Xc=100 Yc=90

group B
a Xa=90  Ya=62, b Xb=100 Yb=87, c Xc=110 Yc91

If I find another covariate for X with a bigger scale (for simplicity lets scale all X 1000 more) the covariance would change between groups. If I carry on, would the ANCOVA give me same results or the scaling of the covariate matters?

Answer (score 1):

The scale of the variable does not, by itself, make any difference (but see below). To see this, think about what would happen if you changed the scale of the same variable - say, you changed kilometers to meters. The parameter estimate would change to match, but the meaning would be the same.

But scaling a variable can make the output easier to read (it's easier to compare 1.2 and 12 than .000000012 and 0.00000000012) and, in extreme cases, the scaling may affect the number of digits displayed or even numerical accuracy.